# How to create Html lock on part of page using JS? (may be Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a part of my HTML page to be visiable to users with enabeld JavaScript only after clicking on to some button, while users with no JS support will seeit always.

So I mean we have a normal page with header and body but with no footer unteel some button is clicked. (while wievers that use no JS modes will see footer always.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could hide the footer using javascript and show it when a button is clicked:

```
$(function() {
    $('#footer').hide();
    $('#someButton').click(function() {
        $('#footer').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery:

```
$(function (){
  $('#footer').hide();
  $('#mybutton').click(function (){
    $('#footer').show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

"Vanilla JavaScript"

```
window.onload = function () {
    var footer = document.getElementById('footer'), someButton = document.getElementById('someButton');
    footer.style.display = "none";

    someButton.onclick = function () {
        footer.style.display = "block";
    };
};
```